# How to set credentials for proxy when connecting to WCF service

Tags: wcf, proxy

I have a program that is a WCF service which connects to third-party WCF service via a proxy server. What I need to specify in app.config to use custom user credentials to this proxy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950928/how-to-specify-windows-credentials-in-wcf-client-configuration-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571277/http-proxy-basic-authentication-with-wcf-channelbase